# Не обновляется информация в блоке до повторного запроса на сервер

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Стартовая страница приложения отдаваемая *сервером* выглядит следующим образом:

`Index.cshtml`

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-hide="!credentials.isAuthenticated">
        <li><a>Hello {{credentials.Name}}!</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="!credentials.isAuthenticated">
        <li><a ng-click="login()">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

*главный модуль* и настройка маршрутизации приложения выглядит следующим образом

```
var cscpApp = angular.module('cscpApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/templates/operation/operations.html',
        controller: 'OperationController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/account/login', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/templates/account/login.html',
        controller: 'AccountController'
    });
});
```

сделал следующий сервис отвечающий за *вход/выход* и получения информации о текущем *сеансе*(`getCredentials()` метод возвращает `json` с информацией о пользователе(name, roles))

```
cscpApp.factory('AccountService', function($http){
    return {
        login: function(loginViewModel){
            let url='';
            return $http.get(url, {model: loginViewModel});
        },
        logout: function(){    
            let url ='';
            return $http.post(url);    
        },
        getCredentials: function(){
            let url='';
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
});
```

*LoginController*

```
cscpApp.controller('LoginController', function($location, accountService){

    accountService.getCredentials().then(function(result){
        $scope.credentials = result.data;
    });

    $scope.login = function(){    
        $location.path('/Account/Login');    
    };

    $scope.logout = function(){    
        accountService.logout().then(function(){
            $location.path('/');
        });    
    };
})
```

*AccountController*

```
cscpApp.controller('AccountController', function($scope, $location, accountService){
    $scope.loginViewModel={};
    $scope.login = function(){
        let url = '';
        accountService.login($scope.loginViewModel).then(function(){
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
});
```

И все *почти* работает: при входе/выходе в/из приложения не обновляется состояние блока отображающего *состояние сеанса* - для авторизованного пользователя приветствие и кнопка `Logout`, для не авторизованного пользователя кнопка `Login`.

Подскажите как переписать код что бы указанный блок обновлялся *своевременно* а не после повторного запроса на сервер.

P.S.: буду премного благодарен за критику кода с пояснениями почему так а не так.

Comment: Держите [mcve]: https://jsfiddle.net/3comgew4/2/

Comment: @PavelMayorov возможно я чего то не понял: в вашем примере реализован случай в котором  аналогичное поведение, после авто *авторизации* так и остается *Hello unknown* хотя надо бы что бы было *Hello John*

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы предлагаете отредактировать исходный вопрос, приведенным примером, так?

Comment: @PavelMayorov ответ я не смог найти. а в вашем примере отсутствует `ngRoute` как компонент. будет ли его отсутствие в примере влиять на ответ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52055/discussion-between-bald-and-pavel-mayorov).